# Equivalent of http://packages.ubuntu.com for partner, security and extras repositories

Tags: package-management, websites

http://packages.ubuntu.com is an amazing website for finding information about packages. I can see how a given package evolved in each release, can compare differences (from Maverick to Precise, for example), download other releases's versions to study or even backport them, etc. It has links to the Debian equivalent, launchpad, etc. It's an amazing cross-release package control panel. I even added its search to my firefox custom searches.

So, the question is:

***Is there any similar website for the partners repository?***

... and what about security? And extras?

My google skills may be rusty, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your highlighted question,

According to [ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/canonical_partner?dist=precise), the partner repository is treated as a 3rd party PPA.

[image]

Thus you can compare the packages in each version of ubuntu by clicking the hyperlinks as shown.

You can compare packages against PPAs to search for the latest package available.

---

Links for:

- [the extras repository](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/extras) is similarly treated as a 3rd party repo.